# PHP Fatal error Parser::parseFile(), Symfony 3.4 + Travis CI

Tags: symfony, phpunit, travis-ci, symfony-3.4

I'm trying to use Travis CI to perform the tests and then deploy to the server.

I have install Symfony 3.4 using composer without including any line of code

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition symfony/ "3.*"
```

I have only create a .travis.yml file to run the test on Travis CI

```
language: php

php:

  - '5.6'


before_script:
  - composer self-update
  - cp app/config/parameters.yml.dist app/config/parameters.yml
  - composer install
```

After doing push with this change, in the job log of Travis CI I get this output

```
$ phpunit
PHPUnit 5.7.23 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser::parseFile() in /home/travis/build/User/PruebaTravis/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php on line 667
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6.32/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6.32/bin/phpunit:592
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6.32/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:116
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6.32/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:186
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6.32/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:517
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6.32/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:722
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6.32/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:722
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6.32/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:868
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6.32/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestResult.php:686
PHP  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6.32/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:913
PHP  11. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6.32/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:1062
PHP  12. Tests\AppBundle\Controller\DefaultControllerTest->testIndex() phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6.32/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:1062
PHP  13. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase::createClient() /home/travis/build/User/PruebaTravis/tests/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultControllerTest.php:11
PHP  14. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase::bootKernel() /home/travis/build/User/PruebaTravis/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/WebTestCase.php:33
PHP  15. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() /home/travis/build/User/PruebaTravis/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php:166
PHP  16. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer() /home/travis/build/User/PruebaTravis/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:137
PHP  17. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->buildContainer() /home/travis/build/User/PruebaTravis/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:642
PHP  18. AppKernel->registerContainerConfiguration() /home/travis/build/User/PruebaTravis/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:774
PHP  19. Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\DelegatingLoader->load() /home/travis/build/User/PruebaTravis/app/AppKernel.php:59
PHP  20. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader->load() /home/travis/build/User/PruebaTravis/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Loader/DelegatingLoader.php:40
PHP  21. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader->loadFile() /home/travis/build/User/PruebaTravis/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php:117
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser::parseFile() in /home/travis/build/User/PruebaTravis/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php on line 667
Call Stack:
    0.0015     490240   1. {main}() /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6.32/bin/phpunit:0
    0.1007   15628304   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6.32/bin/phpunit:592
    0.1007   15637456   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6.32/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:116
    0.1135   16647568   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6.32/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:186
    0.1191   16664024   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6.32/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:517
    0.1193   16667456   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6.32/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:722
    0.1261   16671696   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6.32/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:722
    0.1261   16673800   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6.32/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:868
    0.1262   16677744   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6.32/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestResult.php:686
    0.1264   16696184  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6.32/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:913
    0.1264   16697176  11. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6.32/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:1062
    0.1264   16697352  12. Tests\AppBundle\Controller\DefaultControllerTest->testIndex() phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6.32/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:1062
    0.1264   16697432  13. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase::createClient() /home/travis/build/User/PruebaTravis/tests/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultControllerTest.php:11
    0.1264   16697816  14. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase::bootKernel() /home/travis/build/User/PruebaTravis/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/WebTestCase.php:33
    0.1288   17079808  15. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() /home/travis/build/User/PruebaTravis/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php:166
    0.1319   17408248  16. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer() /home/travis/build/User/PruebaTravis/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:137
    0.1328   17483704  17. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->buildContainer() /home/travis/build/User/PruebaTravis/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:642
    0.2078   25037344  18. AppKernel->registerContainerConfiguration() /home/travis/build/User/PruebaTravis/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:774
    0.2084   25038928  19. Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\DelegatingLoader->load() /home/travis/build/User/PruebaTravis/app/AppKernel.php:59
    0.2084   25039296  20. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader->load() /home/travis/build/User/PruebaTravis/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Loader/DelegatingLoader.php:40
    0.2085   25039864  21. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader->loadFile() /home/travis/build/User/PruebaTravis/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php:117
THE ERROR HANDLER HAS CHANGED!
The command "phpunit" exited with 255.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Comment: Try the following install line: `rm composer.lock && rm -rf vendor && composer validate --strict && composer install` and run phpunit from the vendor folder (`vendor/bin/phpunit`). Later on only validate and install and call from vendor, the removals is just to clean up and remove potential side-effects.

Comment: did this solve the problem?

Comment: I have the same issue. Haven't found a fix yet.

Answer (score 0):

Install `symfony/phpunit-bridge` and execute `vendor/bin/simple-phpunit` instead of `phpunit`

```
$ cd my-project/
$ composer require --dev symfony/phpunit-bridge
$ ./vendor/bin/simple-phpunit
```

It is known issue, and Symfony provides [this solution](https://symfony.com/blog/how-to-solve-phpunit-issues-in-symfony-3-2-applications).